# Youtube API returning 2 requests

Tags: typescript, youtube-api, ionic3, youtube-data-api

im trying to get the latest videos from a channel with youtube api v3 and typescript...
but why it return 2 request?

```
getVideosList() {
return this.http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=' + this.channelId + '&fields=items/id/videoId,items/snippet/publishedAt,items/snippet/title,items/snippet/thumbnails/high/url&maxResults=20&order=date&type=video&key='+ this.apiKey)
.map((res) => {
  return res.json()['items'];
});
```

}

[image]

Comment: I don't think you're showing the relevent part of the code.